# How to write HQL query(Mysql to HQL)?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, hql

I am very new in hibernate.

All entity  are  same as table name and column name.
This query is working fine in mysql.I wants to write this query in HQL.

```
select d.name from Device d 
where d.id in (
    select ud.devices_id from Userdevice ud
    where ud.users_id = (
        select u.id from User u 
        where u.login='" * + uname + "' 
    )
)
```

How i will write this in hql?Please anybody help me.

Comment: You have to provide your entities.

Comment: Clean up grammer, remove noise, retitle question to fit the question and make it easier to find on a search.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (check the tablenames)

```
SELECT dm.name FROM Device dm WHERE dm.id IN (SELECT udm.devicesId FROM Userdevice udm WHERE udm.usersId = (SELECT um.id FROM User um WHERE um.login = ' * + uname + '))
```